# format floating points in matlab using fprintf function

Tags: matlab, floating-point, number-formatting

Consider the following code:

```
A1 = [9.9, 9900];
A2 = [8.8,  7.7 ; ...
      8800, 7700];
formatSpec = 'X is %4.2f meters or %8.3f mm\n';
fprintf(formatSpec, A1, A2)

X is 9.90 meters or 9900.000 mm
X is 8.80 meters or 8800.000 mm
X is 7.70 meters or 7700.000 mm
```

I would like to know what does  `4.2f` or `8.3f`  mean in this case? Does it means how many digit we should use after `.`?

For instance by looking on code, it seems for me  difficult to understand what they mean, while `.2` or `.3` appears a bit clear, first digit `4` and `8` became difficult to interpret, if it is related to mantissa and exponent, then why do we need it there?

Please help me to clarify such things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first number indicates the total number of character spaces (including the delimiting `.`) the number will take up when printed. The second - as you pointed out - represents the number of decimals.
For example, if you print `1.2` with `8.3f` you get three empty spaces before the number:

```
   1.200

12345678 characters total
```

If you were to use `5.2f` your output would be.

```
 1.20

12345 characters total
```

*The second line was added by me to illustrate the total number of characters (including white space). It is not part of the original output*

---

**Edit**
In your example, using `8.3f` for `1.2` wouldn't make much sense. However, if you wanted to write lots of column data to a file that could easily be read by another program, this might be more useful (because the format could be known). E.g. Consider two columns `%8.3f%8.3f` (note how you do not need a space between the floating point number formatter). This could give you an output like this:

```
   1.200  34.564
8503.000 101.008
```

... and so on so forth. Here, the leading blank space helps. It will fail when you have numbers above `9999.999` in this case.

---

**Edit 2**
In Matlab, if you specify a number of total characters that is less than the number of digits you have before the decimal point (or none at all), it will just print the entire number. E.g. using `%2.3f` will give you

```
1.200
```

with no leading white spaces. If you only cared about the decimals printed, you could also use `%.3f` which again results in

```
1.200
```

Comment: wait please,1.200 is 5 character,i can't understand now

Comment: three empty space?why do we need it?

Comment: for example we have  like this $2.3f then it outputs  error right?